# How to solve the error while invoking function through Start-Job?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am having a file named "build.ps1" where there is a function called "Execute-build" available.

I am calling that function from another file named "Dailybuild.ps1" like below.

```
. ./Build.ps1

# starting different jobs (parallel processing)
$job1 = Start-Job { Execute-Build "List.txt" }
$job2 = Start-Job { Execute-Build "List2.txt" }


# synchronizing all jobs, waiting for all to be done
Wait-Job $job1, $job2

# receiving all results
Receive-Job $job1, $job2

# cleanup
Remove-Job $job1, $job2
```

But i am receiving error like follows

> Receive-Job : The term 'Execute-Build' is not recognized as the name
>   of a cmdle t, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
>   spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path
>   is correct and try again.

Why this error occurs and how to resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dot sourced code will not be available in the background job.

One way to solve this is to dot source Build.ps1 in the background job like this:

```
$job1 = Start-Job { 
    . "C:\Path\To\Build.ps1"
    Execute-Build "List.txt" 
}
```

You can also pass the path as a parameter like this:

```
$path = (Resolve-Path ./Build.ps1).Path
$job1 = Start-Job {
    param ($ScriptPath)
    . "$ScriptPath"
    Execute-Build "List.txt" 
} -ArgumentList $path
```

Answer (score 2):

Start-Job open a new instance of `PowerShell.exe` which doesn't have your Execute-Build function. You need to include it  in the `script block` and then call it or use `-InitializationScript` parameter:

```
$a = { function myfunction {return "whatever!"} }
$job = Start-Job {myfunction} -InitializationScript $a
Get-Job
```